# I can't place two elements in line with display:inline-block. How can I solve this?

Tags: html, css, height, width

For example, I have this code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: purple;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```

My elements still behave like blocks. Why? What can explain this problem?

Comment: the duplicate should tell you why 50% + 50% is also comming with extra pixels standing in between your 2 boxes (white-space from the code treated alike  white-space in between 2 img or 2 words ) ;)

Answer (score 0):

remove `inline-block` and wrap them in an element with `display: flex;`. In this case `body { display: flex; }`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block_1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: purple;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```